# Create an Average Variable Using Other Rows in R

Tags: r, average, spatial

I have a dataset where each row represents a country for a particular year. I also have two variables in each row (`Neighbor1` & `Neighbor2`) that list the country codes of that country's geographic neighbors.

**Example Dataset Code:**

```
A=c("US", "Cuba", "France", "Germany", "Belgium", "US", "Cuba", "France", "Germany", "Belgium")  
B=c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001)
C=c(2, 40, 220, 255, 211, 2, 40, 220, 255, 211)
D=c(5, 10, 11, 3, 8, 1, 7, 15, 6, 9)
E=c(40, 2, 211, 211, 220, 40, 2, 211, 211, 220)
G=c(NA, NA, 255, 220, 255, NA, NA, 255, 220, 255)
Example <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E, G)
colnames(Example) <- c("Country", "Year", "CountryCode", "TerrorismDeaths", "Neighbor1", "Neighbor2")
```

**Dataset:**

```
   Country Year CountryCode TerrorismDeaths Neighbor1 Neighbor2
1       US 2000           2               5        40        NA
2     Cuba 2000          40              10         2        NA
3   France 2000         220              11       211       255
4  Germany 2000         255               3       211       220
5  Belgium 2000         211               8       220       255
6       US 2001           2               1        40        NA
7     Cuba 2001          40               7         2        NA
8   France 2001         220              15       211       255
9  Germany 2001         255               6       211       220
10 Belgium 2001         211               9       220       255
```

What I want to do is create a variable that measures that average number of terrorism deaths of each country's neighbor(s) for that particular year. So, I want to add a row that looks like this:

**Desired Output:**

```
   Country Year CountryCode TerrorismDeaths Neighbor1 Neighbor2 NeighborAvgTerror
1       US 2000           2               5        40        NA              10.0
2     Cuba 2000          40              10         2        NA               5.0
3   France 2000         220              11       211       255               5.5
4  Germany 2000         255               3       211       220               9.5
5  Belgium 2000         211               8       220       255               7.0
6       US 2001           2               1        40        NA               7.0
7     Cuba 2001          40               7         2        NA               1.0
8   France 2001         220              15       211       255               7.5
9  Germany 2001         255               6       211       220              12.0
10 Belgium 2001         211               9       220       255              10.5
```

Comment: How large is your data?  Would you accept a brute-force for-loop approach?  How do you want to treat NAs?  (Is this real data?  The US surely has more than one neighbor, unless you are saying e.g. Canada and Mexico are not in the dataset)

Comment: The data is 4605 rows. If the loop approach worked, then that'd be perfectly fine! I want NAs in the neighbors columns not to be considered. Also, you're right that this isn't the full dataset, as Canada and Mexico are also the US' neighbors (and are coded as such in my full dataset)

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished in three steps

1. Reshape dataset from wide to long format
2. Aggregate within a self-join
3. Append result column to original dataset using an update join

with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(Example), measure.vars = patterns("^Neighbor"), 
             value.name = "Neighbor", na.rm = TRUE)
agg <- long[long, on = .(Year, Neighbor = CountryCode), 
            mean(TerrorismDeaths), by = .EACHI]
Example[agg, on = .(Year, CountryCode = Neighbor), NeighborAvgTerror := V1]

Example[]
```

> ```
>     Country Year CountryCode TerrorismDeaths Neighbor1 Neighbor2 NeighborAvgTerror
>  1:      US 2000           2               5        40        NA              10.0
>  2:    Cuba 2000          40              10         2        NA               5.0
>  3:  France 2000         220              11       211       255               5.5
>  4: Germany 2000         255               3       211       220               9.5
>  5: Belgium 2000         211               8       220       255               7.0
>  6:      US 2001           2               1        40        NA               7.0
>  7:    Cuba 2001          40               7         2        NA               1.0
>  8:  France 2001         220              15       211       255               7.5
>  9: Germany 2001         255               6       211       220              12.0
> 10: Belgium 2001         211               9       220       255              10.5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way but this works:

```
## Create an empty dataframe with a row for each country.
NeighborAvgTerror <- data.frame(NeighborAvgTerror=double(length(A)))

## Go through every country
for(i in 1:length(A)){
  ## Get neighbor code 
  n1_code<-Example$Neighbor1[i]
  n2_code<-Example$Neighbor2[i]
  year<-Example$Year[i]

  ## Find terrorism deaths for neighboring countries
  n1<-Example[which(Example$CountryCode == n1_code & Example$Year == year), ]
  n2<-Example[which(Example$CountryCode == n2_code & Example$Year == year), ]

  ## Average while ignoring the nulls
  NeighborAvgTerror$NeighborAvgTerror[i]<-mean(c(n1$TerrorismDeaths,n2$TerrorismDeaths),na.rm=T) 
}

## Append to Example dataframe
Example<-cbind(Example,NeighborAvgTerror)
```

I see that you have more than 2 neighbors in your comments, and you can edit the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) packages [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) and [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

deaths <- Example %>% select(CountryCode, Year, TerrorismDeaths)
neighbors <- Example %>% select(CountryCode, Year, matches('Neighbor[0-9]+'))

Example %>% 
  gather(Neighbor_num, Neighbor, matches('Neighbor[0-9]+'), na.rm = T) %>% 
  left_join(deaths, by = c(Neighbor = 'CountryCode', 'Year'), suffix = c('', '_neighbor')) %>% 
  group_by(Country, Year, CountryCode, TerrorismDeaths) %>% 
  summarise(NeighborAvgTerror= mean(TerrorismDeaths_neighbor, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  arrange(Year, CountryCode) %>% 
  left_join(neighbors, by = c('CountryCode', 'Year'))

# # A tibble: 10 x 7
# # Groups:   Country, Year, CountryCode [?]
#    Country  Year CountryCode TerrorismDeaths NeighborAvgTerror Neighbor1 Neighbor2
#    <fct>   <dbl>       <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1 US       2000           2               5              10          40        NA
#  2 Cuba     2000          40              10               5           2        NA
#  3 Belgium  2000         211               8               7         220       255
#  4 France   2000         220              11               5.5       211       255
#  5 Germany  2000         255               3               9.5       211       220
#  6 US       2001           2               1               7          40        NA
#  7 Cuba     2001          40               7               1           2        NA
#  8 Belgium  2001         211               9              10.5       220       255
#  9 France   2001         220              15               7.5       211       255
# 10 Germany  2001         255               6              12         211       220
```

---

If you need to build a dataset of neighboring/adjacent countries first, you can use the [CoW Direct Contiguity dataset](http://www.correlatesofwar.org/data-sets/direct-contiguity).

```
library(curl)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

url <- 'http://www.correlatesofwar.org/data-sets/direct-contiguity/direct-contiguity-v3-2'
tmp <- tempfile()
curl_download(url, tmp)
csv_file <- unzip(tmp, files = 'DirectContiguity320/contdird.csv', exdir = tempdir())
unlink(tmp)

# level of separation options
# 1: Separated by a land or river border
# 2: Separated by 12 miles of water or less
# 3: Separated by 24 miles of water or less (but more than 12 miles)
# 4: Separated by 150 miles of water or less (but more than 24 miles)
# 5: Separated by 400 miles of water or less (but more than 150 miles)

neighbors <- 
  read_csv(csv_file, col_types = 'iiciciid') %>% 
  filter(year >= 2000) %>%  # filter to only years you need
  filter(conttype <= 4) %>%  # choose level of separation
  select(CountryCode = state1no, Year = year, neighbor = state2no) %>% 
  group_by(CountryCode, Year) %>% 
  mutate(Neighbor = row_number()) %>% 
  spread(Neighbor, neighbor, sep = '')

unlink(csv_file)

deaths <- Example %>% select(CountryCode, Year, TerrorismDeaths)

Example %>% 
  select(-Neighbor1, -Neighbor2) %>% 
  left_join(neighbors, by = c("Year", "CountryCode")) %>% 
  gather(Neighbor_num, Neighbor, matches('Neighbor[0-9]+'), na.rm = T) %>% 
  left_join(deaths, by = c(Neighbor = 'CountryCode', 'Year'), suffix = c('', '_neighbor')) %>% 
  group_by(Country, Year, CountryCode, TerrorismDeaths) %>% 
  summarise(NeighborAvgTerror = mean(TerrorismDeaths_neighbor, na.rm = T)) %>%
  arrange(Year, Country) %>%
  left_join(neighbors, by = c('CountryCode', 'Year'))
```